# Using STL map for searching for points lying in a rectangular area?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have with me a lot of x,y points and each x,y point has some extra data associated with it. This extra data I'll be storing in a struct.
My application requires that given any one point, I'll have to find how many other points lie within a rectangular area surrounding this point (this point is at the centre of the rectangle).

One logic I've thought of is to store all x points as the keys in a map A and all y points as the keys in another map B. 
Map A will have x as the key and y values as the value.
Map B will have y as the key and the associated struct as the value.

This way, if the given point is (10.5,20.6), I can use upper_bound(10.5+RECTANGLE_WIDTH) and lower_bound(10.5-RECTANGLE_WIDTH) to find the range of x values lying within the rectangle and for the corresponding y values, find whether the y values lie within the +- range of 20.6.

My whole point of using map was because I have a massive store of x,y points and the searching has to be done every two seconds. So I had to use the log(n) search of map.
I feel that this can be done in a more efficient way. Suggestions?

Comment: "I have with me a lot of x,y points " ... Are your points "static"?

Comment: @belisarius: Yes. All x,y points are static const.

Comment: @Nav so, why don't pre-compute the number of points near each point and add that to your "structure"

Comment: @belisarius: You didn't ask yet if the rectangles always have the same size.

Comment: @Sven I assumed they are because the OP used uppercase in the var names ... perhaps I assumed too much :D

Comment: @belisarius: Nice suggestion, but I wouldn't want to store the surrounding points as it would take up a lot of extra memory, and I need the application to be flexible enough that even if the point to search for is not within the set of static const points available, the program should be able to find the nearest points. Yes, the rectangle is always the same size.

Comment: So I think @Sven's answer is what you are looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a typical application for a [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).  The quadtree facilitates lookup of the m points lying in your rectangle in O(log(n) + m), where n is the total number of points.

Edit: Your approach using the map is not nearly as efficient.  For randomly distributed points, it would have an O(sqrt(n)) average complexity, and O(n) worst-case.

Comment: Actually, I've heard that the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve is more efficient than the quadtree. It's just that I haven't every used either of them, so I thought a map would be quicker to implement.

Comment: @Nav: I don't think a data structure based on space filling curves can be more efficient than a quadtree.  And it is certainly more cumbersome to implement.  A quadtree is really easy, just try it!

Comment: certainly some sort of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index is the way to go - i'm not sure we have enough information to say which type is best - though quadtree is probably a good place to start

Comment: jk: Thanks for the pointers. It's going to be a much better investment in time to learn the quadtree algo, than to go ahead with a map implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

How about you store the points as a simple 2 dimensional array of pointers to those structs, and when you need to find a point x,y it's a simple index operation. The same goes for any other points (x+a,y+b).

Comment: Are you assuming the x ,y are integers?

Comment: This works very well for a small area mostly filled with points, but very poorly for large spaces, especially when they're sparsely populated.

Comment: I was assuming that they were integer points. But it would work relatively easily with floating point as well, as long as you could round appropriately.

Comment: Also from what the question stated I assumed that every point on the map had a structure associated with it, but I left the possibility to have empty areas by using pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a std::map of points the lookup will always be O(log N) where N is the number of points you have.

Your other option would be to divide your search space into buckets and put your point into buckets. You then calculate in your rectangle:

- any buckets for which all the points are inside your rectangle
- any for which there is some overlap.

For those that there is some overlap you can then look up in your collection which is O(M) if you use the right collection type per bucket, but M should be smaller than N. It may even be that M rarely exceeds a handful in which case you can probably check them linearly.

Working out which buckets overlap is a constant time operation but you have to run through these linearly (even to check if they are empty) so having too many of them may also be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first observation would be that `std::map` wouldn't be the most efficient structure in any case. Your input is pretty much fixed, apparently (from the comments). In that case, `std::binary_search` on a sorted `std::vector` is more efficient. The main benefit of `std::map` over a sorted `std::vector` is that insertion is O(log N) instead of O(N), and you don't need that.

The next observation would be that you can probabaly afford to be a bit inaccurate in the first phase. Your output set will probably be a lot smaller than the total number of points (else a linear search would be in order). But assuming that this is the case, you might benefit from rounding up your rectangle. This will result in more candidate points, which you then check against the precise boundary.

For instance, if your points lay randomly distributed in the XY plane between (0,0) and (200,300), it would be possible to create a 20x30 matrix with each holding an subarea of size (10,10). If you now need points in the rectangle from (64,23) to (78, 45), you need to check subareas `[6,2], [6,3], [6,4], [7,2], [7,3] and [7,4]` - only 6 of the 600. In the second step, you'd throw out results such as (61, 25).